# long waiting time in linking

Tags: time, long-integer, building

here is the situation.
I am using visual studio 2005.
the solution contains lots of projects, 34 projects in all, and the start up projects depends on others.
then in linking part, it'll wait a long time before the real linking starts.
I am pretty sure it's because of too many projects depended, as when I use a solution with 10 of the 34 projects(keep other projects as headers&libs), it'll start instantly.

so any one has any idea that I can reduce the waiting time?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

If 10 is fast and 34 is incredibly slow, you might try adding projects one-at-a-time to the 10-project solution until it gets slow. There may be one particular project that causes the slowness.

Comment: As it's enumerating dependancies, it may get exponentially more complex. I'd second adding back a single project at a time and see where the slowness starts to occur - whether it's a particular project or a certain number of projects.

Comment: If you find that your machine just starts bogging down at a certain # of projects in general, check out task manager, you might be maxing out CPU or RAM with devenv.exe or perhaps another process is eating up system resources.  If so, its pretty cheap these days to dump in some more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off "Whole Program Optimization", that should speed up the linking for you.  Then you could use it in your final stages of release.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the option in link-general-enable Incremental linking

Or
[Unity Build](http://buffered.io/2007/12/10/the-magic-of-unity-builds/)

will useful for you